# Equalizing Height of two columns with jquery .css

Tags: jquery, css, height

I'd like two equalize the Height of two columns in a row.
For this task I want to use jQuery.

At the moment I embedded the custom.js and it gets loaded but something inside this file ist wrong and I hope you can give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong, please =)

For testing, this is the content of my .js:

```
$(window).load(function() {
var indval001 = $(".indcol1").outerHeight(true);
var indval002 = $(".indcol2").outerHeight(true);
var indval003 = ((indval001 - indval002)/2)
$(".indcol3").css({
    'margin-top' : indval003 + 'px',
    'margin-bottom' : indval003 + 'px'
});});
```

Great thank you in advance and apologize my poor english xD

Comment: you can simply do this with below jquery plugin. Its easy, simple and quick.
-- https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height

Comment: ..or just use flexbox

Comment: Flexbox was my First idea,but in the second column there is a picture,then text,then again a picture while in the First column there are only pictures. Problem is,all pictures have different sizes! Only the margin of the text is adjustable! With flexbox they either align on top or at the bottom,but they have to align both! So please Tell me,what I have to change in the js,please.

Answer (score 0):

No plugin needed.

```js
var col1 = $('article:first-child'),
    col2 = $('article:last-child');

if ( col1.outerHeight() > col2.outerHeight()) {

  $(col2).css('height', col1.outerHeight());
  
} else {

  $(col1).css('height', col2.outerHeight());
  
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

p {
  margin: 0 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <article>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
      <p>Short paragraph</p>
  </article>
</div>
```